# Why doesn't the "else if" statement in JQuery work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

My `else if` statement doesn't work breaks my script. Why is this happening?

```
    function validateForm (){

    var loginStr;

    loginStr = $("#login").val();



        if (loginStr.length == "") {
            $("#formPseudoContainer").effect('shake', 750 );
                $("#errorArea").text('PLEASE CHOOSE USERNAME');
        };          

        else if (loginStr.length > 0 && loginStr.length < 5) {
            $("#formPseudoContainer").effect('shake', 750 );
                $("#errorArea").text('USERNAME IS TOO SHORT');
         }; 
     }
```

This works fine:

```
       function validateForm (){

    var loginStr;

    loginStr = $("#login").val();



        if (loginStr.length == "") {
            $("#formPseudoContainer").effect('shake', 750 );
                $("#errorArea").text('PLEASE CHOOSE USERNAME');
        };          

        if (loginStr.length > 0 && loginStr.length < 5) {
            $("#formPseudoContainer").effect('shake', 750 );
                $("#errorArea").text('USERNAME IS TOO SHORT');
         }; 
     }
```

I threw out other similar statements, so I cannot just use an `if` and `else` statement.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Oh, you get a syntax error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The semicolon at the end of the `if` statement terminates the `if` statement; remove it, and it will work.

Comment: Now i feel retarded. Thank you very stupid junior mistake from me. Must sleep more. Thank you.

Comment: It's an easy one to make!  But yes, sleep is good :)

Answer (score 3):

Length never returns null if string had been no length it returns 0 and remove semicolon for if contion it ends it doesn't go other check other elseif

```
 if (loginStr.length == 0) {
    $("#formPseudoContainer").effect('shake', 750 );
        $("#errorArea").text('PLEASE CHOOSE USERNAME');
 }         

else if (loginStr.length > 0 && loginStr.length < 5) {
    $("#formPseudoContainer").effect('shake', 750 );
        $("#errorArea").text('USERNAME IS TOO SHORT');
 }
```

Comment: Due to JS' type coercion, `loginStr.length == ""` would still work though. It's unintuitive and horrible(!), but it works.

Answer (score 0):

because if is terminated by ; after } remove ; after }

```
   if (loginStr.length == "") {
        $("#formPseudoContainer").effect('shake', 750 );
            $("#errorArea").text('PLEASE CHOOSE USERNAME');
    }          

    else if (loginStr.length > 0 && loginStr.length < 5) {
        $("#formPseudoContainer").effect('shake', 750 );
            $("#errorArea").text('USERNAME IS TOO SHORT');
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
function validateForm (){

    var loginStr;

    loginStr = $("#login").val();

    if (loginStr.length == "") {
        $("#formPseudoContainer").effect('shake', 750 );
            $("#errorArea").text('PLEASE CHOOSE USERNAME');
    } else if (loginStr.length > 0 && loginStr.length < 5) {
        $("#formPseudoContainer").effect('shake', 750 );
            $("#errorArea").text('USERNAME IS TOO SHORT');
    }; 
}
```

remove the extra ";" at the end of IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

An [`if` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) consists of the `if` keyword, a condition, and a **single** statement, i.e.

```
if (condition) statement
```

In your case (which is good practice), you choose the statement to be a [**block**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) `{...}`:

```
if (condition) {...}
```

However, you also put a semicolon after the block. That semicolon is interpreted as [**empty statement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Empty). It is not part of the `if` statement:

```
if (condition) {...}
;
```

To make the `else if` work, it has to immediately follow the statement belonging to the `if` statement, there cannot be any additional statements (even empty ones) between them.

Comment: That semicolon is actually my Text Editor's auto fill..very bad mistake.

Comment: Doesn't matter where it comes from ;)